# using if condition to addclass in return value using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have values in an array to display in a div, when I click on a particular button, two array values will swap their positions. But I want to add different background color to the div after swaping.. 
**My sample code is :**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    var PlanetsModel = function() {
    self.Racer = ko.observableArray([
        { id: "Racer-101", rank: "5"},
        { id: "Racer-102", rank: "2"},
        { id: "Racer-103", rank: "1"},
        { id: "Racer-104", rank: "4"},
        { id: "Racer-105", rank: "7"},
        { id: "Racer-106", rank: "8"},
        { id: "Racer-107", rank: "9"},
        { id: "Racer-108", rank: "3"},
        { id: "Racer-109", rank: "6"}
    ]);

    console.log("First array : " + JSON.stringify(self.Racer()));

    this.hideElement = function() {
        function swap(data, x, y) {
            var target = document.getElementById('remove_elem'),
                getRacer = target.children[x];
                getRacer1 = target.children[y];
                console.log(getRacer);

                var temp = data[x];
                data[x] = data[y];
                data[y] = temp;
                console.log("swap values");

                if(self.Racer()[x].rank > self.Racer()[y].rank) {
                    console.log('first element is greater');
                    $('#first').removeClass('sample'); 
                    $('#first').addClass('highlight');
                } else {
                    console.log('second element is greater');
                    $('#first').removeClass('sample'); 
                    $('#first').addClass('remove');
                }
        }
        swap(self.Racer(), 1,3);
        self.Racer.valueHasMutated();
    }; 
    this.showRacer = ko.computed(function() {
       return self.Racer();        
    }, this);
};
ko.applyBindings(new PlanetsModel());
});
```

**my html code:**

```
<button id='swap' data-bind='click: hideElement'>Swap Values</button>

<div id='remove_elem' data-bind='template: { foreach: showRacer }'>
    <div style="width: 50%;" data-bind='attr: { "class": "planet "}'>
        <div class="left" data-bind='text: id'></div>
        <div class="right" data-bind='text: rank'></div>
        <span id="first" class="sample">xxx</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

This is my sample code, it will swap values when the button is clicked. but it's adding color in the first element of the array only.
what is the problem in my code ?.

Comment: Whers is your HTML? Could you please post a full exemple?

Comment: Can't do anything without your HTML markup

Comment: In the `if..else` you're always removing / adding a class to the same element (`#first`).

Comment: I want to remove class #first and add different class for the same div for particular swap values. How is it possible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always changing the value of the div with id `first`.

id's have to be unique and so none of the other ones with the id of `first` are changing because jquery  stops searching for others after it finds the first element you're looking for.

You should add something to the id that makes it unique to that racer, like making the id of the div the same as the id of the racer. for instance: `data-bind='attr: { "id": "id"}` (where the second id is the id of the racer object).

then you reference it again in your javascript by calling the same id related to that racer object like `$("#"+racer[x].id)`

Updating your code it should look like this, if I'm understanding your use of data-binding code correctly.

```
<button id='swap' data-bind='click: hideElement'>Swap Values</button>

<div id='remove_elem' data-bind='template: { foreach: showRacer }'>
    <div style="width: 50%;" data-bind='attr: { "class": "planet "}'>
        <div class="left" data-bind='text: id'></div>
        <div class="right" data-bind='text: rank'></div>
        <span data-bind='attr: {"id": "id" }' class="sample">xxx</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

and javascript can be updated like this:

```
if(self.Racer()[x].rank > self.Racer()[y].rank) {
    console.log('first element is greater');
    $('#'+self.Racer()[x].id).removeClass('sample'); 
    $('#'+self.Racer()[x].id).addClass('highlight');
} else {
    console.log('second element is greater');
    $('#'+self.Racer()[y].id).removeClass('sample'); 
    $('#'+self.Racer()[y].id).addClass('remove');
}
```

Comment: I add $('#first'+self.Racer()[y].rank) in my code, there is  no other color change in the rows..

Comment: @NewUSer I've updated my answer a little, try the thing with the id and check in the html that is rendered by inspecting it with your browsers debugger to make sure that the id value is getting set as expected as I'm unsure how your data binding library works so my example might not be 100% correct in terms of syntax

Comment: I should remove quotes in id data-bind='attr: {"id": id }', it should perform change color on one value.. I want to change color on both swapped values..

Comment: Then I guess it's just down to what you have in your `if` and `else` blocks. You need to add the class to change the highlighting to each div you want the highlighting changed on, but you'll have `$('#'+self.Racer()[x].id)` and `$('#'+self.Racer()[y].id)` in the `if block where you change their classes to whatever it is that highlights them.

I'm having a little trouble understanding your english and what you actually want in these comments now though.

Comment: this example will works correctly. I will add only one class in only if and else statement. there is the problem in my code. I will add both two class in $('#'+self.Racer()[x].id) and $('#'+self.Racer()[y].id) in if and else statement. They should perform correctly

Comment: I have doubt with this example, I will add background image to the add class they should not show images. It will be empty